# Passing a Var and List to Controller via Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a Text Box and a Select Options Multiple, i store all the selected items using knockout selectedOptions in a viewModel.

If I try to pass the captured information to my Controller using ajax I'm unable to recieve my MetricsChosenModel.

```
            var MetricsChosenModel= window.vm.MetricsChosenModel();
            var ApplicationsNameValue = $.trim($("#add-Applications").val());
            if (ApplicationsNameValue.length <= 0) {
                $("#text-add-Applications").popover('show');
            }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/AddApplications',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { ApplicationsName: ApplicationsNameValue, MetricsChosenModel: MetricsChosenModel },
                    success: function (returndata) {
                        if (returndata == true) {
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
```

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult AddApplications(string ApplicationsName,List<string> MetricsChosenModel)
    {

        //Code here
        return View();
    }
```

My MetricsChosenModel stores data in following format
MetricsChosenModel[0] => 5
MetricsChosenModel [1] => 6

why am i not able to recieve the list value of MetricsChosenModel , I'm able to recieve the ApplicationsName though,

Also it would be great if some one can explain, how am i wrong here,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your routing looks like, it's hard to pinpoint the exact source of the problem. If I had to guess, I'd say that you're getting the `ApplicationsName` value through the URL (routing or querystring parameter). If that's the case, you could probably add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the `MetricsChosenModel`. Note, however, that you're only allowed one `FromBodyAttribute` per method signature. If you need more variables, a simple solution to this problem is to create a model which contains each of the properties you're looking to receive in your controller action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Edited the question to be more precise, I get ApplicationsName from my text box, and i store "select combobox multiple" information in my MetricsChosenModel. My question is why am i not able to pass simple string variable `ApplicationsName` and a list `MetricsChosenModel` to my controller. I'm able to recieve string variable `ApplicationsName` though, but not the list

Comment: My answer remains the same: Add `[FromBody]` to the `MetricsChosenModel` argument in the desired action method. Because the `ApplicationsName` parameter's type is a primitive (string), the framework is able to pass the value through the URL either as a route value or as a querystring parameter. However, I don't believe it will attempt to push the list value into the querystring. Therefore, you'd need to read that value from the request body. You can test my theory by running Fiddlr to view the posted request.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem myself with ASP.NET MVC: sending a model with some fields and one or more arrays up to a controller would not properly get the array contents into the C# model. The following change to the ajax call fixes it for me every time:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/AddApplications',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // ADD THIS
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: JSON.stringify({ ApplicationsName: ApplicationsNameValue, MetricsChosenModel: MetricsChosenModel }), // Also added JSON.stringify
                success: function (returndata) {
                    if (returndata == true) {
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
```

The 'content-type' and 'JSON.stringify' help MVC with converting the model. Please let me know if that helped for you too :)

Comment: Hi Mate, Thanks for replying, I already knew this stringify. But dont u think its an overhead ? Firstly to Stringify and in the controller to Decode ? Assume that in the list there are 100s of items. When we can recieve a simple string in an ajax call, why not a list is all my question about.

Comment: In my experience, the overhead is negligible. In our application, we send arrays of thousands (if not more) of reasonably complex objects over the line this way, without problems. I don't know the details of why ASP.NET can't handle the arrays properly without it because I'm mainly concerned with the frontend, it has something to do with the modelbinding logic it uses. If you don't want to stringify, I think your best bet is to hook into the modelbinder, see what it does and if you can fix it by overriding that logic. We've tried that, but never got it quite right.

Comment: Technically, the framework is having to decode and execute model binding no matter which format you choose for transport. By leaving off `content-type=application-json` you're implying a content type of `multipart/form-data`. The only real potential for noticeable, potentially unwarranted overhead is if you were excluding the json2.js library from your network stack. Even then, probably not worth eliminating JSON as a format option. That said, I still think `[FromBody]` will solve your problem ;)